# Sanity checking the effective sample size

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

When running MCMC sampling, a common measure of performance is the effective sample size (ESS).

There are lots of different ways to estimate the ESS from samples e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.0175.

In high dimensions all of these estimation techniques can be tricky. Is anyone aware of some sanity checks that one can perform to ensure that the estimate is reliable/trustable?

Thanks!